# headers with access from domain only

Tags: php

I have this test.php code in one of my web pages.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$links = array(
    'dolhd' => '/dohd.m3u8',
    'dol1' => '/dol1.m3u8',
    'dol2' => '/dol2.m3u8',
    'dol3' => '/dol3.m3u8',
    'thd' => '/thd.m3u8',
    't1' => '/t1.m3u8',
    'test' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OWt8O8pgw0',
);

$id = $_GET['id'] ? ($links[$_GET['id']] ? $_GET['id']: 'test') : 'test';
header ('Location:'.$links[$id]);
ob_flush();
exit;
?>
```

The page is accessed from the browser like this `test.php?id=dol1` and the result is downloading the file dol1.m3u8

I want to know if it is possible for that page to be accessible only from another page from the same domain.

Or to block access for all ip-s except the domain.

Comment: You can restrict access to this page via domain's IP only by refering to certain IP-address in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - that's mostly reliable option.

Comment: you can't do that... because who supposed to open that link? whose on your domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]!=="your.domain.here"){
//redirect or whatever - referrering url not from this domain
            }else{
ob_start();
$links = array(
    'dolhd' => '/dohd.m3u8',
    'dol1' => '/dol1.m3u8',
    'dol2' => '/dol2.m3u8',
    'dol3' => '/dol3.m3u8',
    'thd' => '/thd.m3u8',
    't1' => '/t1.m3u8',
    'test' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OWt8O8pgw0',
);

$id = $_GET['id'] ? ($links[$_GET['id']] ? $_GET['id']: 'test') : 'test';
header ('Location:'.$links[$id]);
ob_flush();
exit;
}
```

Just makes sure you have "your.domain.here" replaced with the desired string for your domain. More info here -> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: No, you can not rely on `HTTP_REFERER` value in terms of security since it is sent by _client_ - and, therefore, can be fake

Comment: when i enter the adress it dosent work its good. but when i make a reqwest from another page it dosen't work either. thats not good!

Comment: Echo the output of http_referer and check your using the same format. I'd bet there is a better way security-wise however this would work for a prototype/testing until you find a more effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your redirected file header and change ip address with yours:

```
<?php
$allow = array("192.168.10.1", "192.168.10.2", "192.168.10.3");

if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow)) {
   echo "Your access denied!";
   exit();
} 
?>
```